# Shell script for coppying files from one directory to another

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to write a shell script to copy files with some specific name and creation/modification date from one folder to another. I am finding it hard that how I can do this ?

However i have tried this till now.

```
srcdir="/media/ubuntu/CA52057F5205720D/Users/st4r8_000/Desktop/26 nov"
dstdir="/media/ubuntu/ubuntu"
find ./ -type f -name 'test*.csv' -mtime -1
```

Now my question is, is it possible to put that find command into a if condition to get the files found by `find`. 
I am very new to shell script. any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your `find` command is incomplete.  `-mtime` needs a parameter and you are not supplying one.  Are you looking to copy all `*.csv` files from all subdirectories to a single destination directory, or is there a requirement to preserve directory structure?  Anyway, look for `find ... -exec cp -t`

Comment: @tripleee thank you for commenting and mentioning all these. However i found a solution with the `find ... -exec cp -t` command. But i ran into another problem. How can i print some message when the copy is happen. and how i can print some message when its failed to copy files. because i want to create a log file as well.

Comment: Trivially, add a `-v` option to the `cp` command line.

Comment: Please see the answer i have given for this question. I have used that. it simply prints the paths on the terminal. How can i save that into a variable to write it on a file later ?

Comment: `command 2>file` writes the standard error output from `command` to the file `file`. Saving in a variable is not something I would recommend.

Comment: Got that. But can you just tell me how can i save it on variable ? just for my knowledge. :)

Comment: `variable=$(command 2>&1)`.  If you need a search engine, I recommend http://www.google.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found useful for this is the following code. I am sharing this here so that some one who is new like me can take some help from it:

```
#!/bin/bash

srcdir="/media/ubuntu/CA52057F5205720D/Users/st4r8_000/Desktop/office work/26 nov"
dstdir="/media/ubuntu/ubuntu"

find "$srcdir" -type f -name 'test*.csv' -mtime -1 -exec cp -v {} "$dstdir" \;
```